# Target Class [Auth\LoginController] Not Exist In User Authentication In Tenant Stancl/tenancy

Tags: php, multi-tenant, laravel-6.2

I am using the Stancl/Tenancy package in laravel for multi-tenancy system.

I'm able to login from the central app but not from the tenant app in my localhost.
I have created a virtual central domain in localhost named **sms.com** and a subdomain named **tenant1.sms.com**

When I open the central domain the login page appears and I'm successfully able to login but when I open the tenant app which is **tenant1.sms.com** I get the following error:

**Target class [Auth\LoginController] does not exist.**

I have read and implemented the code from this link: https://tenancyforlaravel.com/docs/v3

Link for universal route in the below code: https://tenancyforlaravel.com/docs/v3/features/universal-routes

Following is my tenant route code:

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>['web',InitializeTenancyByDomain::class,PreventAccessFromCentralDomains::class]
],function () {
    Route::middleware(['universal'])->group(function () {
        Auth::routes();
    });
    
    Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function () {
        Route::get('/', function () {
            return 'This is your multi-tenant application. The id of the current tenant is ' . tenant('id');
        });
    });
});
```

When I don't use the Authentication, the above string is being diplayed

*This is your multi-tenant application. The id of the current tenant is tenant1*

Am I missing something for authentication in tenant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the solution. Just wanted to share in case someone else is looking for in the future or got stuck in a similar case.

Adding namespace `namespace('App\\Http\\Controllers\\')` in the below code will fix this problem.

`Route::middleware(['universal'])->namespace('App\\Http\\Controllers\\')->group(function () { Auth::routes(); });`

Comment: Great!. Please are you able to update user's profile photo on tenant's site?

Answer (score 0):

You should set namespace in `app/Providers/TenancyServiceProvider.php`:

```
// By default, no namespace is used to support the callable array syntax.
public static string $controllerNamespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';
```